# VB.Net how can I amend this simple RegEx to accept numbers and "/"?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have this:"^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*$"
It works great, I keep posting stupid posts about RegEx because I'm useless with them and come to this forum for help every time (should I stop).

I need to make to RegEx allow "/" and numbers so that the user can input something like "Testing12/02/2013".

As an added bonus I wouldn't mind if it limited the user to numbers at the end of string but that is not important xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your actual regex: `^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*$`, just add the characters you want in the second part:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?: ?[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)*$
//           ^^ optional space
```

Comment: This new RegEx still doesn't seem to accept inputs like "test2012" or "test12/02/2011". Could someone please give me one that does?

Maybe it's down to the "+(?:"

Comment: @TurgidWizard: just make the space optional: ` ?`, see my edit